# iOS 10 message effects send to phone number but not email address

Tags: messages, ios

If I send an iMessage to my son using his phone number, the new message effects work without issue.  If I send an iMessage to him using his email address (still in Messages), they do not work and show the parenthetical text (["Sent with xxxx effect"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/255612/21351)) when he receives the message.  When I send it, I see the desired effect.  Neither of us have reduce motion or anything of the sort turned on.  Note that they are both "blue" iMessage conversations.

I've tried deleting the conversation where it was failing (to his email) and that didn't change anything.

Is there a reason why he would see the effects if I send to his phone number vs. his email address?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what your question is? It's not very clear.

Comment: I wonder how you can send them differently to start with. Are both messages sent via iCloud (blue background)? Does your son have his email address linked to his phone number? What is the shown as the sender on your side if your son sends an iMessage to you?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252704/can-i-disable-receiving-effects-in-ios-10-messages (the answer to your question is containted in the question there, actually)

Comment: @patrix I've updated the question and I don't think it's contained in the other question

Comment: Is his email address the same address as his Apple ID?

Comment: Take a look [at this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/271781/how-to-fix-imessage-not-showing-message-effects-in-ios-10/) and be sure you follow all the steps (you can skip the reduce motion section).  See if any of these help.

Comment: @fsb yes email is his apple id

Comment: @fsb will try the steps from the article and try again

Comment: Is the other end running iOS 10?

Comment: @bret7600 Yes both sides are ios 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may sound bizarre but you obviously have searched and checked and/or corrected the most common reasons of why it does not work correctly.

There is one thing that I am seeing a lot of on forums that you have not mentioned.

> I fixed this by going to Settings/Messages, then turning iMessage on
>   and off.