# Can I disable receiving "effects" in iOS 10 Messages?

Tags: ios, messages, settings, accessibility

For reasons past comprehension, the new iOS 10 Messages app allows applying "effects" to messages. I understand that I can disable the ability to *generate* these abominations by choosing

> Settings > General > Accessibility > Reduce Motion

Will this also (please!) disable their *receipt*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling that feature will result in a text-only message accompanying the message where the effect was sent stating, e.g.

> (sent with Slam Effect)

This replaces the effect being generated.

Comment: So if someone sends me a message with a "Slam Effect" — God, I remember when I thought we were going to use all this tech to go to Mars and solve poverty! — and I've turned on "Reduce Motion", I'll just see that parenthetical taunt, and no actual "effect", right?

Comment: Correct. ------

Comment: [This no longer works in 10.1.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/258620/4395)

Comment: True, but the new setting is literally directly below that.

Comment: The new setting doesn't do what the old one did. The old on prevented *generating* effects too.

Comment: This question was about preventing receipt of them.

Comment: Yes, it stays accepted and upvoted for that reason. It no longer solves the premise of the question though, that there is a setting for disabling their generation (it seems).

Comment: I believe the premise is flawed, in that there is a very simple solution: just don't send them. You have to go through several steps to send them. It's not as if you can do it by accident. Why should there be a setting to prevent you from doing something that you have to actively choose to do in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure what's confusing you here. The question contains the statement  "I understand that I can disable the ability to generate these", so that's part of the premise. Whether that should be expected is not relevant.