# What words trigger the screen effects in iMessage?

Tags: ios, messages

The recent update iMessage on iOS causes certain words to trigger screen effects. 
Also, [there is a way to long-press on the send button](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-add-screen-effects-to-imessages-in-ios-10/), and bring up an interface for adding these effects.

I've found the following associations between screen effects, and the messgaes that trigger them:

- confetti: "congratulations", "happy birthday"
- fireworks: "happy new year"

What is the list of these?

Comment: I’m going to assume you want a wiki style list of X and convert this to wiki. We should have a discussion on [meta] if it gets closed or this gets edited to not be a listing exercise.

Comment: @bmike seconded. That's what I thought too when I wrote the answers(now one)

Comment: Newest needs defining unless the intent is to delete all answers each week when a new word gets added in some localization.

Answer (score 7):

- Happy Birthday: Balloons
- Congratulations: Confetti
- Happy New Years: Fireworks
- Happy Chinese New Years: Celebration
- Pew pew: Light/Laser Show

Also if you hold down the send button you can access a set of effects you can add to your message like a (Slam/Loud/Gentle/Invisible Ink). Now if you hold down the send button, not only do you get those set of effects, but the effects above with the SHORT list of trigger words are accessible at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 10.2, the messages in the question are the only ones I could find that trigger a full screen effect, no others have been confirmed in the sources I looked at ([Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206894), [iMore](http://www.imore.com/how-to-use-bubble-and-screen-effects-imessage-iphone-ipad), [iGeeksBlog](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-add-screen-effects-to-imessages-in-ios-10/)).

So our list is:

- "Congratulations" or "Happy Birthday": Confetti
- "Happy New Year": Fireworks
- "Pew pew": Light/Laser Show
- „Eid Mubarak“: shooting star

Given that I can't find evidence of any other "trigger messages", I think it's safe to say that these are the only ones.

Answer (score 2):

Just add to the list if you find some triggers. No need to remove the obsolete, as in some OS, they might still be working.

- *Congratulations!* coloured ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​paper cuttings
- *Happy Chinese new year!* ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ works in other countries too.
- *Happy new year!* different from above.
- *Happy Birthday!*  balloons.
- *Pew Pew* lights in different colours
- *Eid Mubarak* Shooting Star

Answer (score 1):

The words...

- `Best wishes` shows 2 hands giving some stuff out.
- `XOXO` shows some hearts

Comment: If you don't mind - want to edit these in to the best answer that has all the list of these maintained?

Comment: Doesn't work as of iOS 13.4